# java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 72

Tags: jmeter

The request URL has stringified json

```
Sampler Result:
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2013-09-05 12:09:17 IST
Load time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 4491
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 4491
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in query at index 72:

Request:
GET  http://abc.com/api/api_name?XYZModelJsonString={[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]{}}
[no cookies]

Response data:
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 72: http://abc.com/api/api_name?XYZModelJsonString={[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]{}}

at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:234)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1077)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 5):

Move the following:

> XYZModelJsonString ={[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]{}}

In the parameters table putting XYZModelJsonString in name column and the rest in value column and check encode checkbox in the column.

[image]
It will work

Comment: No. I have tried this but does not work. When I encode I get the following response code.

Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

Comment: The URL is as follows:

"http://abc.com/api/api_name?XYZModelJsonString={%22param%22:%22[{\%22param\%22:\%221\%22,\%22param\%22:\%222\%22,\%22param\%22:\%22500.00\%22,\%22param\%22:15000,\%22param\%22:0,\%22param\%22:null,\%22param\%22:true,\%22param\%22:\%22-\%22,\%22param\%22:0}]}"

Comment: I edited answer, I tested it and get this : /api/api_name?XYZModelJsonString=%7B%5B%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%5D%7B%7D%7D not what you show