# Extracting authenticity token for login using JMeter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, jmeter, token

```
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="sn0fmV699N6hHzljhZPqzk+WSaRh9WPspQ5fa/dd6nA=">
```

I want to extract `sn0fmV699N6hHzljhZPqzk+WSaRh9WPspQ5fa/dd6nA=` from the above HTML.

I tried using `input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="(.*?)"/>` but it doesn't return anything. can someone pls help on it ??

Comment: <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="sn0fmV699N6hHzljhZPqzk+WSaRh9WPspQ5fa/dd6nA="> this is my html which I want the value to be extracted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are getting above Token in response to one of your request. So identify that request and add PostProcessor>Regular Expression Extractor under it. Use following values in it.

```
Reference Name: ExtractedToken
Regular Expression: <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="(.+?)" /></div>
Template: $1$
Match No: 1
Default Value: Token Error
```

Add a debug sampler in your Test Plan, this will help you see if anything is being stored in variable named "ExtractedToken". If you see your expected value in this variable that means Regular Expression extractor is working fine.

Now you can use this variable in all those requests where token value will be required.

Reg Expression Example: https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743642

Login Example: https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743663-how-to-use-jmeter-for-login-authentication-

Comment: I'm very new to JMeter so could u pls explain how should I use the value that I stored in regular expression extractor in samplers ??

Comment: I have added more details in my answer. check now.

Comment: This is wat the error is:
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 67: http://esaki.freshmarketeer.com/sign_in?utf8=â&authenticity_token=${auth_token}&user[email]=esaki@freshdesk.com&user[password]=test1234
 at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3111)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
 at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
 at java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:939)
 at

Comment: This reg exp worked for me. I have tested it on your website..   <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="(.+?)" /></div>

Comment: Yup, I succeeded with the way that you suggested but after that POST request I couldn't head to anywhere as the response of tat request is "App-loading". can u help me on that ?

Comment: Try these links.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651722/java-net-urisyntaxexception-illegal-character-in-query-at-index-72
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124444/jmeter-http-request-java-net-urisyntaxexception-illegal-character-in-query-at-i

Comment: If these do not solve your problem, then you can create a new question with all details/screenshots. Hopefully you will get the solution. :)